# C++ Comparing Doubles

Tags: c++, comparison, double

Is there any known problem using < or > with doubles?

```
d1 > d2

d2 > d1
```

I cannot find anything that would indicate that this would be a problem.

However, I assume this will be a problem due to the issues with equality and I will have to use "almost equal" logic using Epsilon:

```
d1 >= d2

d2 >= d1
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: Have you done a search for "double comparison c++" or "floating point comparison c++" on SO? I'm asking because I'm not really sure what you want to know. Taking a look at the most common questions regarding floating point comparison could help you.

Answer (score 1):

`>` and `<` work exactly as expected; if the value of `d1` is greater than the value of `d2`, then `d1 > d2` will be `true` (and vice versa).  The problem (if there is one) is that `d1` and `d2` might not be exactly the values you expected.

However, replacing `>` with `>=` will change the behaviour for exactly one value of `d1` (for a fixed value of `d2`).

Comment: All six comparison operators work "exactly as expected", if you expect the right things:-).

Comment: @James Kanze: Thanks, I know that one and consider it a must-read for any developer working with numerical math (my field). However, the paper only mentions comparison operators in relation to NaNs. I would really like some good/intuitive summary of the comparison operators and their practical issues.

Comment: @Andre I can understand that; the cited work only describes the
underlying situation; it doesn't go into the impact on application code
and what to do about it.  And the issues can be subtle; if the `double`s
are the results of a function call, returned in a floating point
register, the compiler may end up comparing the floating point register
(with extended precision) with a value spilled to memory (with double
precision).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you may get a 'false positive' where there are two variables `d1` and `d2` which you deem to be of equal value. In that case if you do `d1 > d2`, there is a chance the expression will evaluate to true.